# Print an equilateral triangle in J language

Tags: loops, j

I a trying to print a equilateral triangle to the console screen. 
this is what I could find

```
]\ 'hello' NB. which prints
h
he
hel
hell
hello
```

Comment: what is your input and what is the expected output that you are looking for?

Comment: Well, if possible i was hoping for a function that can accept an integer argument. something like this:  equitriangle=: <code> 5 to create a triangle with a height of 5

Comment: Can you update your post to show your expected output for the input of 5?

Comment: here is an example from another language: Enter value of n : ? 5                          
 Output:
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
********* Output may not be properly rendered here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First solution that I came up with is this:

```
   eq=. ('b< >' 8!:2 (] ,.~ |.@}."1)@:([: >:/~ i.)) 
   eq 5
    1    
   111   
  11111  
 1111111 
111111111
   eq 10
         1         
        111        
       11111       
      1111111      
     111111111     
    11111111111    
   1111111111111   
  111111111111111  
 11111111111111111 
1111111111111111111
```

`eq` is a verb that first takes the argument and creates a matrix with the lower left of `1`'s using `([: >:/~ i.)`, this is then fed to `(] ,.~ |.@}."1)` which drops the first character of each line then reverses before appending to the original matrix. Finally, to get rid of the ugly `0`'s I use the foreign conjunction `8!:2` which formats the binary array into characters and the left argument `'b< >'` specifies that `0`'s will be replaced with blank spaces.

Second solution:

```
   eq2=: ([ ,.~ |.@}."1)@:(]\) 
   eq2 'hello'
    h    
   ehe   
  lehel  
 llehell 
ollehello
   eq2 '*******'
      *      
     ***     
    *****    
   *******   
  *********  
 *********** 
*************
```

`eq2`  works the same way except it uses your `]\` initially which means that the format  foreign conjunction is not necessary, as the result fed to `([ ,.~ |.@}."1)` is already in character form.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your effort bob! It seems that it will take me long time to figure out how to output other types of patterns.Once more, thank you.

Comment: No worries, keep playing and you will get the hang of it. If you like the answer, give it an upvote so that people know that it has been answered, but only if you think it is a good enough answer.

Comment: Also I edited your question by using the markup to show your result as code, which allows it to look the way that you would expect. This can't be done in comments as far as I know, just answers and questions.

Comment: I don't have enough 'rep'  on SE to upvote!  But I appreciate all the help you are giving.

Comment: Happy to help. Enjoy J :-)

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from your ]\, which makes a matrix of characters, you want to put the reverse (|.) of each line, concatenated (,) by the line itself with the first character dropped (}.). You want to do that line by line, rather than for the whole matrix at once, which is specified by "1 .

In other words: (reverse concat drop) rank 1, or in J: (|. , }.)"1

```
(|. , }.)"1 ]\ 'Helloooo'
       H       
      eHe      
     leHel     
    lleHell    
   olleHello   
  oolleHelloo  
 ooolleHellooo 
oooolleHelloooo
```